# I have some confidential pdf's they have to show in browser but they are not meant to downloaded by any means

Tags: jquery, html, pdf, browser

I have some confidential  pdf's (Company Policies etc.,) they have to show in browser but they are not meant to downloaded by any means...

is there any possible way please help me...

Comment: The problem you have is that anything displayed can be copied (i.e downloaded) - even by a basic print screen capture.

I'd have a rethink about the strategy for this - if they can view them, what's the problem in downloading them?

Comment: Thats the clients req. there's ntng much to say about clients mentality.. I think you know that well.. :)

If you see in this sites like
http://www.yumpu.com/en
issuu.com

I am in need of the similar functionality to those websites....

For example you can see this link A dummy pdf is uploaded
http://issuu.com/ikyaglobaleducation/docs/being_a_professional_in_software_te

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, once you show something up in the browser, [it becomes inevitably downloadable by the user](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/18449). Especially with `PDF` that *has* to be [downloaded on the remote computer in order to be viewable in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10846759/2788131). Therefore, one could go into the browser cache to retrieve the file, let alone the possibility for one to `Save as` the file.

Keep in mind that if you don't want something to be downloaded, you will have to **not share it online** by uploading them on a web-server publicly accessible (even if restricted with some credentials).

This client request is a complete non-sense. What you need to do is to convince him that this requirement is absurd and silly and goes against the essence of internet.

Long story short, [there is no way to accomplish what you want](https://answers.acrobatusers.com/how-can-i-make-a-pdf-viewable-but-not-downloadable-from-the-web-q234382.aspx).